# Eclipse RCP switch workspace

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, workspace

I am developing an RCP application (3.x), and i would like to implement eclipse's switch workspace feature, only way i found is that using ActionBarAdvisor but this extension is already deprecated.

```
protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        IWorkbenchAction switchWorkspaceAction = IDEActionFactory.OPEN_WORKSPACE.create(window);
    register(switchWorkspaceAction);
    }
```

How can i implement this by using org.eclipse.ui.commands extension point? Which plugins are supporting this?

Comment: What are you saying is deprecated here?  In any case this action doesn't appear to have a command id associated with it.

Comment: When i add this action to MenuManager it doesn't show up in rcp, and when try for org.eclipse.ui.actionSets it says this extension point is deprecated. How can i associate this action with a command?

Comment: You can't associate Actions with a command. You would have to write your own command handler and try calling the action from that.

Comment: and eclipse provides switch workspace implementation through only actions?

Comment: The only thing that displays the choose workspace dialog and does the switch is the action accessed through the `IDEActionFactory.OPEN_WORKSPACE` factory.

Comment: thanks a lot! @greg-449